# Is this study stating red algae reduces cold virus by 92% believable?

Tags: common-cold, clinical-study

I was using this spray meant to hasten recovery from the common cold. [This study](http://trials.boehringer-ingelheim.com/trial_results/clinical_trials_overview/1326/1326_1.html), sponsored by the pharmaceutical company that produces the spray, stated it reduced virus by 92%, and so shortens the duration of the common cold.

Meanwhile a doctor told me that these kinds of things don't work.

Does someone have some perspective on this? Is this a believable study? Was it well designed, and has it been duplicated?

If so, why wouldn't the pharmaceutical produced a certified and expensive drug instead of a no-prescription drug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this from the perspective of an infectious disease epidemiologist, the kind of person who often reads (and occasionally runs) studies of this type, I'm skeptical. A number of reasons why:

- The only results are a synopsis. More details and data are apparently available, but there is no manuscript, and their "[Transparency Policy](http://trials.boehringer-ingelheim.com/transparency_policy/policy.html#accordion-1-5)" has a *lot* of caveats in it.
- It's not a peer reviewed study.
- Their treatment protocol is oddly variable - 4 mandatory days plus a possible additional six days based on...?
- Again, since they're not providing tables, this gets a little frustrating to try to consider, but their treatment arm is fairly heavily skewed toward women - they claim it's similar in the control arm, but they won't show you how similar.
- They fail at their primary endpoint, being the mean number of symptoms reported between the treatment and control. The mean number of symptoms are about half-a-symptom less between the treatment and control arms, but the result isn't statistically significant, they do some statistical adjustment I'm a little skeptical of - because they don't describe it - and they end up using somewhat...loose...language like "was a strong trend in favour of Bisolviral®."
- This is all based on patient self-report of symptoms, and interestingly, there's *absolutely* not an effect for self-reported assessment of efficacy between the treatment and control arms. Further, looking at viral load assays, there's also no *biological* evidence that anything is happening.

I can't find the specific language about the 92% claim you cite in your question, but my assessment of the overall evidence that this compound works would be "Faint and preliminary, at best".

Comment: Since the link said "Full text" I thought it had the full text, and not a synopsis of the result. The 92% claim is in the promotional material from the spray.

Meanwhile I found some other "similar studies" (I think), and asked a more broad question. It's [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/831/are-these-studies-about-red-algae-reducing-cold-virus-by-92-believable), if want to have a look. Thanks!